# Pass data to JavaScript variable from Handlebars in Keystone.JS

Tags: handlebars.js, keystonejs

I am using Handlebars for my views and I want to pass returned data from database to javascript/jQuery. What will be the similar logic to this code in Handlebars?

```
//These lines of code are from Jade template.
  <script type="text/javascript">

    var SydJS = {};
    SydJS.meetup = !{JSON.stringify(meetup)};

 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

use triple curly braces {{{ }}}

See http://handlebarsjs.com/ `HTML Escaping`